# Unity prefab object position overrides coded Instantiate position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the line below to create balls in 1 of 3 random locations.  Balls are prefab Image objects being parented to a canvas.  The prefab object has a position of 0,0 in the Unity inspector so it keeps creating the balls in the middle of the Canvas.  How can I get Unity to create the objects in the Instantiate position (i.e the Vector2 from spawns[]) instead of using the RectTransform position from the prefab?

```
    Instantiate (ball, spawns [Random.Range (0, 3)], Quaternion.identity, parent);
```

Comment: You should provide a bit more of your code.

Comment: From what I can tell, this should work as you expected. The transform should be set to `spawns[Random.Range(0, 3)]`. I suspect the problem is in another part of your code. Perhaps the Start method of your ball script? We'd need to see more code to help.

Comment: See also [`bool instantiateInWorldSpace`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html).